# Force browser to target the iframe

Tags: iframe, jplayer

In my website, except header and footer, the whole thing is an iframe. But, of course, when i reload the page, the site gets reloaded to the first page. How do i avoid that and tell the browser to reload the iframe instead the html?

Comment: As with most things on here m8 people expect you to have at least tried a few things yourself first.  If you get stuck then ask for help with the bits your stuck on.  Your question is too open ended or is asking someone to tell you how to code the whole thing.

Comment: @SubstanceD I'm sorry. I'm kind of new here but thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a URL is a unique locator, so every time you reload the page you get back to the same place.

To avoid this, you need to store somewhere the current URL of your iframe, and include a script that can retrieve this URL. Two common ways to do this are:

- store it locally (use localStorage or a cookie)
- store it in the hash part of your URL, for example:

  http://mySite.com#/pages/home.html

  http://mySite.com#/pages/aboutus.html

As @SubstanceD said in the comments, to get a more specific answer you'll certainly need to show something specific you've tried.

Comment: so how will i store or run any other function from the iframe? and how will i edit the url?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "run any other function from the iframe" and "edit the url", but again you are expected to do a minimum of research and show what you've tried.